# Ethereum transaction sent from Ledger Nano X stuck because too low tranasction fee used

Tags: nonce, fees, coinbase

My ETH are STUCK.
48 hours ago i sent 31 ETH from my Ledger Nano X to my Coinbase account, but i choose the slowest and cheapest method that was diplayed into my ledger ( I don't remember how much gas and GWEI was but definitely i choose the slowest and cheapest one because i was not in a rush and i thought in maximum 10-12 hours will be completed but now after more than 48 hours I'm getting anxious especially after reading on several places that my transation could be stuck in the network and I really don't know how long it could take until miners will verify it  and I really don't know what to do if is anything to do other than wait.
Definitely was very stupid from me doing what I've done but now apparently is nothing to do than wait.
Any help,suggestions or alternative please? Still learning every day...
Thank you! Appreciate it.

Comment: Technically you can increase the gas price for the current transaction nonce or alternatively you can send a new transaction with higher gas price. Then your stuck transaction will become invalid. The exact procedure will depend on whatever program you are using, see also https://ethgasstation.info/blog/stuck-transaction-guide/.

Comment: @MironAlexandru did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.